# receive multiple notifications and remove notification in android

Tags: android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

In my project I am working with notifications. I successfully received multiple notifications with registration id its fine. My problem is when ever I use remove notification with same registration ID it shows only one notification on notification bar. I want to show all notification on notification bar and if I select one notification it has to remove from notification bar. Please tell me any solution
mycode:

RegIdDTO.java:

```
public class RegIdDTO {
    public static final int REG_ID= (int) Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
}
```

intentservice.java:

```
public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService{
    Context context;

    //System.currentTimeMillis();

    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
    public static final String TAG = "GCM Demo";

    public GcmIntentService() {
        super("GcmIntentService");
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        String msg = intent.getStringExtra("message");
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);


         if (!extras.isEmpty()) {

             if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                        MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
                    sendNotification(RegIdDTO.REG_ID,"Send error: " + extras.toString());
                } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                        MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
                    sendNotification(RegIdDTO.REG_ID,"Deleted messages on server: " +
                            extras.toString());
                // If it's a regular GCM message, do some work.
                } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                        MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
                    // This loop represents the service doing some work.
                    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Working... " + (i+1)
                                + "/5 @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(500);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        }
                    }
                    Log.i(TAG, "Completed work @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                    // Post notification of received message.
                    //sendNotification("Received: " + extras.toString());
                    sendNotification(RegIdDTO.REG_ID,msg);
                    Log.i(TAG, "Received: " + extras.toString());
                }
            }
         GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }
    private void sendNotification(long when,String msg) {
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


        Intent myintent = new Intent(this, ReceiveActivity.class);
        myintent.putExtra("message", msg);
        myintent.setData(Uri.parse("content://"+when));

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1,
                myintent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_gcm)
        .setContentTitle("Event tracker")
        .setContentText("Events received");
        Notification notification=mBuilder.build();


        AudioManager am = (AudioManager)this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

        /* Even if the mode is set to "Sound & Vibration" in the phone, 
         * the status code that getRingerMode() returns is RINGER_MODE_NORMAL.
         */
        switch (am.getRingerMode()) 
        {
            case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE:
                mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);
                break;
            case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL:
                mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
                break;
            default:
                mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
         }




        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

      mNotificationManager.notify((int) when, mBuilder.build());
     // serv.CancelNotification(getApplicationContext(), (int) when);

        }

    public void CancelNotification(Context ctx) {
        String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
        NotificationManager nMgr = (NotificationManager) ctx
                .getSystemService(ns);
        nMgr.cancel(RegIdDTO.REG_ID);


    }
}

receiveactivity.java:

Context mContext;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_receive);
Intent intent = getIntent();


name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
deal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.deal);
valid = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.valid);
address = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.address);
String message = intent.getExtras().getString("message");
try {
    json = new JSONObject(message);
    String stime = json.getString("name");
    name.setText(stime);

    String slecturename = json.getString("deal");
    deal.setText(slecturename);

    String sroom = json.getString("valid");
    valid.setText(sroom);

    String sfaculty = json.getString("address");
    address.setText(sfaculty);


} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    serv=new GcmIntentService();
    serv.CancelNotification(getApplicationContext());
}

}
```

Comment: Is that code worked to you. If it works then don't forgot to tick the right mark for the answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
private static void sendNotification(Context context, String message,
            String keys, String msgId, String branchId) {
        NotificationCompat.Builder nBuilder;
        Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager
                .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        nBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("header")
                .setLights(Color.BLUE, 500, 500).setContentText(message)
                .setAutoCancel(true).setTicker("Notification from s")
                .setVibrate(new long[] { 100, 250, 100, 250, 100, 250 })
                .setSound(alarmSound);
                // write your click event here
            Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, MainLoginSignUpActivity.class);

    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
            notify_no, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            // Show the max number of notifications here
    if (notify_no < 9) {
        notify_no = notify_no + 1;
    } else {
        notify_no = 0;
    }
    nBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    NotificationManager nNotifyMgr = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    nNotifyMgr.notify(notify_no + 2, nBuilder.build());
}
```

Comment: thanku for u r response kertheek,please explain the parameters in this]   private static void sendNotification(Context context, String message,
            String keys, String msgId, String branchId)

Comment: remove unnecessary params keep those are usefull to you. I think context and message are necessary for you...

Comment: long when = System.currentTimeMillis(); where u use this variable

Comment: icon and when are unneccessary for this code. currenty I deleted some code and pasted over there

Comment: how we can this value notify_no using                       endingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
            notify_no, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

Comment: Declare as global  `private static int notify_no;`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48353/discussion-between-kartheek-s-and-bharat)